# Powershell: /TargetFile you must provide a value expression following the '/' operator error

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to implement the following example ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/apps/cd/sql-server-actions?view=vsts). Very first example) in my VSTS powershell script to create a database snapshot (.bacpac) file but get

> the '/TargetFi ...
>   +                                                                  ~
>   You must provide a value expression following the '/' operator' error.

Tried many things but this error is persistent in the inline script of my Powershell task. Seems like this error is quite common in running variables and similar sort of situations but I couldn't find an answer to my specific problem.

```
'C:ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe' /TargetFile:"<C:\Temp\test.dacpac>" /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:"<localhost>" /SourceDatabaseName:"<MyDataBase>" /SourceUser:"<sa>" /SourcePassword:"<MyPa55w0d>"
```

Comment: Your immediate problem is that in order to execute a file path _in quotes_, you must use the call operator: `& '...' ...`

Comment: I have added the & operator and getting the following error 'The term 'C:ProgramFiles(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe' is not recognized as the name of a 
cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify 
that the path is correct and try again.'

Comment: Didn't split the code intentionally. Copied pasted from the linked website and it automatically split into 3 lines

Comment: The beginning of the command would be `C:\Program Files (x86)`, not `C:ProgramFiles(x86)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [call operator](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) like this:

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /TargetFile:"<C:\Temp\test.dacpac>" /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:"<localhost>" /SourceDatabaseName:"<MyDataBase>" /SourceUser:"<sa>" /SourcePassword:"<MyPa55w0d>"
```

Otherwise PowerShell is just saying "hey that's a nice string", oh, what does this `/TargetFile` switch mean?

To see what I mean run:

```
"notepad.exe"
```

Should just print the word "notepad.exe" as a string. This one:

```
"notepad.exe" C:\temp.txt
```

Gets confused as it doesn't know what to do with the `C:\temp.txt` argument you're passing to a string.  To get it to launch notepad.exe creating a new file:

```
& "notepad.exe" C:\temp.txt
```

Works!

Comment: `C:ProgramFiles(x86)` probably doesn't exist. It should be `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Even better: `${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Oops, I don't have it installed anyway, so never checked the path!  Updated my answer to a more valid path.

Answer (score 0):

All of the above comments and the answer added a value and helped me to resolve my problem. Following is my answer (for any newbie like myself) and some key points that I have learnt

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe" /TargetFile:"C:\Temp\test.dacpac" /Action:Extract /SourceServerName:"localhost" /SourceDatabaseName:"MyDatabase" /SourceUser:"sa" /SourcePassword:"MyPa55w0d"
```

- Should start with & sign as suggested by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) and [Daniel Morritt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505667/daniel-morritt)
- SQLPackage.exe path was wrong. It should be

> C:\Program Files (x86), not C:ProgramFiles(x86)

as suggested by [Bill_Stewart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2102693/bill-stewart)

- Values shouldn't be enclosed by the angle brackets (<,>). Inline Powershell don't recognise these brackets and I was getting the error. Don't know if it is same by running the script from a script file and different versions.